# CSS - Problema con ajuste responsivo utilizando background-image

Tags: html, css, responsive, sass

Tengo un problema al momento de remplazar imagenes dependiente de la medida de la pantalla.
Tengo mi elemento `header` el cual le paso un `background-image`

```
SCSS -

header{
 height: 100vh;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center top;
 background-size: cover;

 @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
      background-image: url("./assets/interno.jpg");
  }
 @media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
       background-image: url("./assets/externo.jpg");
  }
}
```

Tengo mi ventana a más de `1200px` por lo tanto debería tomar el `interno.jpg` pero no! esta tomando el banner `externo.jpg`

¿Alguien sabe cual es la mejor manera de trabajar con `background-image` y **responsive**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifica primero si tienes en tu "head" el meta del viewport para responsive

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Si esta todo bien la modificación que haría seria la siguiente.

**CSS:**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1400px) {
    header {
        height: 100vh;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center top;
        background-size: cover;
        background-image: url("./assets/interno.jpg");
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    header {
        height: 100vh;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center top;
        background-size: cover;
        background-image: url("./assets/externo.jpg");
    }
}
```

Dentro de las etiquetas de las medias queries establezco que es lo que realizara para que se vean los cambios

Comment: Me sigue colocando la segunda imagen, no esta respetando el `min-width`

Comment: O establece un "min-width" y un "max-width" y puedes ir jugando con la resolución. El cambio esta en la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Debes colocar el breakpoint o 'media query' del menor ancho de pantalla por encima del mayor ya que el orden de lectura de CSS es arriba a bajo teniendo más peso lo último escrito:

```
  @media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
     header {
         height: 100vh;
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         background-position: center top;
         background-size: cover;
         background-image: url("./assets/externo.jpg");
      }
   }

 @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px){
     header {
         height: 100vh;
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         background-position: center top;
         background-size: cover;
         background-image: url("./assets/interno.jpg");
     }
 }
```